# Responsinve Form which will initially display data from an PHP variable in a Table

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[my requirement form link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6q7otndtfm2qwe/my%20from.png?dl=0)

I have made an html form that displays data from an PHP variable. The Form contains a table and that table has number of rows based on a PHP variable.
but problem is that form is not responsive can you please give some idea how can i made a responsive form with table that will load data from an PHP variable. my current code is below:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <form method="POST" action="/updateInfo" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="InfoForm">
                            <div style ="width:100%; height:250px;">
                                <table style = "width:100%;border:2px;height:60%;"> 
                                    <tr style = "border-bottom: thin solid;background-color:#9a004b;color:White">
                                        <th></th>   
                                        <th>Register Date</th>
                                        <th>Reconciliation Date</th>
                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                        <th>IBAN</th>
                                        <th>Withhold</th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php   foreach($overpayment as $key=>$value){
                                            if(empty($value['ReconciliationDate'])){
                                    ?>              <tr  style="border:1px solid #9a004b;background-color: White">
                                                <div class="row">   
                                                    <td><input type="hidden" name=OverpaymentNr[] value="<?php echo $value['OverpaymentNr']?>"</td>
                                                    <td><label name=Paydate[] value=""/><?php echo $value['RegisterDate']?></td>
                                                    <td><label name=ReconciliationDate[] value=""/><?php echo $value['ReconciliationDate']?></td>
                                                    <td><label name=Amount[] value=""/><?php echo $value['Amount']?></td>


                                                    <td><input type="text" style="width:186px; height:35px;" name=IBAN[] value="<?php echo $value['IBAN']?>"/> </td>
                                                        <td><label name=Withhold[] value=""/><?php echo $value['Withhold']?></td>

                                                </div>
                                                </tr>   
                                    <?php       }
                                        } 
                                    ?>
                                        <tr  style="border-top:1px solid #9a004b;">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td align="center"><input type="Submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" name= Submit value = Submit /> </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>    
                            </div>

                        </form>     
                        </div>  
            </div>
```

Comment: Responsive as in "it will re-size according to display" ? If so, nothing to do with php but purely css / html, further more, from what I can see you haven't even tried to make it responsive.

Comment: yeah my target is like that it will resize according to display but i found examples that contain predefined data in html/css not preparing based on some fetched data. is it possible to do that?

Comment: You mean css classes? You even tagged twitter bootstrap which offers plenty of responsive classes.

Comment: yeah i am using Twitter bootstrap but i didn't find any example that will serve my purpose. I mean creating a bootstrap form with table inside which will load data from a PHP variable. u can have a look at my code.

Comment: Aye, but on twitters page they are showing you plenty of examples of how to use responsive classes, even with your form.

Comment: I went through the examples again but didn't find any similiar examples, probably i was unable to make u understand my requiremnt. u may go through attached picture.